# Wamp Server with windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, wampserver

I am running WAMP server on windows 8.1 . I have installed wamp on D: Drive whereas other windows and system files are under C: Drive. I want to reset my PC. Does this effects my WAMP server? Do i have to install WAMP again?

Note : I just want to reset my operating system not re install operating system.

Answer (score 1):

No you wouldn't, misread question.

Answer (score 1):

As long as Your Windows is installed on the C: drive a resetting Windows will not damage WAMPServer on the D: drive.

However when you get windows reset it might not know about the WAMPManager icon on the desktop or the Apache and MySQL services.

All you need to do is this :-

Make a new shortcut of `D:\wamp\wampmanager.exe` on your desktop.

Run Wampmanager just like normal, the icon will stay RED.

Now do

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
```

Now WAMPServer should be properly instaled again, just as it was before.

So do a

```
left click wampmanager -> Restart All Services
```

and the icon should go GREEN

Comment: what about my database those are already there?? Installing mysql service again wont harm them?

Comment: In this case the menu item `Install Service` just registers the Apache and MySQL services with Windows Service Manager. It does not install MySQL or Apache